# Accessing dictionary inside a dictionary as attribute in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am making a simple **Entity Component System** in python using dictionaries (I heard they have better performance somehow), but I didn't wanted access the data like `foo['bar']['x']`, and wanted to access it more like `foo.bar.x` (just personal preference)

So I made this code

```py
class Entity(dict):
    def __init__(self, dictionary={}):
        super().__init__(dictionary)

    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        return self[attribute]

foo = Entity([('PositionComponent', {'x': 0, 'y': 0})])
```

So, I can access the PositionComponent as `foo.PositionComponent`
but I cant access the x value as `foo.PositionComponent.x`

How could I make it work? And is there a better way to make what I've already made?

---

**UPDATE**

I made three versions of the same ECS in python

1. Using Entity classes without extending dict `foo.component(bar).x` (for loop in foo.component)
2. Using Entity classes extending dict `foo['bar']['x']`
3. Using Entity classes extending dict and accessing components with custom __getattr__ `foo.bar.x`

Using a particle system, with 133 particles on screen at any time, as test I got the FPS of each ECS
[image: Particle System Used]

This are the results:

1. FPS around  750
2. FPS around 1050
3. FPS around  500

So this proves that using custom **__getattr__** makes the code run **2x slower than using normal dicts**

**Max particles on screen**
[image]
(left: FPS, Right Particles)
(Color disabled, circle gets drawn even with radius 0)
(12000 to reach 30 FPS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the `x` value because it belongs to a `dict` instance, not a `Entity` one. A possible workaround would be to only use `Entity`.

Also, since you're inheriting from `dict` you can use `**kwargs` for building your objects.

```py
class Entity(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        return self[attribute]

foo = Entity(PositionComponent=Entity(x=0, y=1))
print(foo.PositionComponent.x)
>>> 0
```

Comment: if I use kwargs it gives this error `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

The first part works fine tho

Comment: @Nath Can you share how you've used it?

Comment: oh, I spotted the problem, I was declaring the entity as i've done before `Entity([('PositionComponent', {'x': 0, 'y': 0})])`, when I used `Entity(PositionComponent = Entity(x=0,y=1))` it worked